# Qual a finalidade e como utilizar corretamente o hasManyThrough do Eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-eloquent

**Qual finalidade do hasManyThrough do Eloquent?**

Lendo a documentação, entendi (provavelmente de forma errônea), que este método de relacionamento nos permite acessar uma tabela através de uma tabela de relacionamento. Seria isso?

**O problema**

Tenho as seguintes tabelas:

```
profile:
   id
   name

permissions:
   id
   name

profile_permissions:
   id
   profile_id
   permission_id
```

O Que eu quero fazer é criar um relation na profile para acessar diretamente o nome da permissão.

Se eu usar o `hasMany`, ao acessar apenas como `$profile->permissions`, tenho o retorno de um array da Model `ProfilePermission`, o que me obrigaria a fazer dois `foreach` para acessar de fato o nome das permissões.

Minha ideia é criar uma relation onde `$profile->permissions` retorne diretamente a model `Permission`, que aí sim, possui o nome da permissão.

Pra isso tentei usar o `hasManyThrough`, da seguinte forma:

```
public function permissions()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(
        Permission::class,
        ProfilePermission::class,
        'profile_id',
        'permission_id',
    );
}
```

Porém, não funciona. Logo recebo um erro de query `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'permission.permission' in 'on clause'`

Estou utilizando a abordagem correta? Existe um método que seja mais apropriado para este cenário? Ou de fato é o `hasManyThrough`, mas estou o utilizando incorretamente?

Grato, desde já.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O método hasManyThrough do Eloquent permite que você crie uma relação entre duas tabelas que não têm uma relação direta, mas sim através de uma tabela intermediária. Isso significa que você pode acessar dados de uma tabela através de uma tabela de relacionamento. No seu caso, você quer acessar a tabela permissions através da tabela profile_permissions.

Para fazer isso, você precisa informar o modelo final (Permission), o modelo intermediário (ProfilePermission) e as chaves estrangeiras que relacionam essas tabelas. Em seu código, você está informando corretamente os modelos, mas está usando as chaves estrangeiras incorretamente. A chave estrangeira da tabela profile_permissions que relaciona com a tabela profiles é profile_id, e a chave estrangeira que relaciona com a tabela permissions é permission_id. Então, a correção seria:

```
public function permissions()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(
        Permission::class,
        ProfilePermission::class,
        'profile_id', // chave estrangeira na tabela intermediária que relaciona com profile
        'id', // chave primária na tabela final
        'id', // chave primária na tabela inicial
        'permission_id', // chave estrangeira na tabela intermediária que relaciona com permission
    );
}
```

Espero que isso te ajude a resolver o problema.

Answer (score 1):

Então Wallace, pelo que vi, é uma relação ManyToMany, pois "N" Profiles pertencem a "N" Permissions, vice-versa. o "HasManyThrough" acessa uma tabela mais distante, como há na própria documentação do Laravel:

```
projects
    id - integer
    name - string
 
environments
    id - integer
    project_id - integer
    name - string
 
deployments
    id - integer
    environment_id - integer
    commit_hash - string
```

Ou seja, no exemplo dado, a intenção é acessar a model "deployments" pela model "projects", através da model "environment", resumidamente não é o seu caso.

Como você tem uma relação N-N, o $profile->permissions irá retornar todas as permissões vinculadas a ele, ou seja, para que você acesse os nomes, precisa executar um loop das informações, já que irá existir permissão1, permissão2 e sucessivamente.

Você pode utilizar a Collection "pluck" para retornar somente uma coluna do código, mas mesmo assim, irá receber um array das diversas permissões, ficando assim:

```
$profile->permissions->pluck('nome-da-permissao');
```